# Automatically selecting and uploading files in Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

How can my test case can automatically/ randomly can select a native file from the path as shown below in Selenium IDE?

I have used the following command with target and set the path in the value field where my files are located:

`command=type, target=id=studentsFileInput, value=C:\\Users\\admins\\Downloads\\Excel format\\DataSheet`

This is the path where my files are stored. So which command can be used that can automatically select any of the files from those stored file from the path given.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is that it should pick file randomly and upload it. Right now i am giving hard coded filename in the path